# Xdebug breakpoints not working on Sublime Text 3

Tags: php, debugging, sublimetext3, xdebug

Trying to use Xdebug on Sublime Text.
Followed all the instructions when installing to Sublime. Installed Xdebug client via the package manager. Added the path mappings and URL to Xdebug.sublime-settings

```
"pathMappings": {
        "/var/www/html": "path_to_folder_with_project"
    },
    "url": "http://local.testapp.com/",
```

Installed Xdebug extension using pecl to my machine.

Then updated my `php.ini` file like so:

```
zend_extension="xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable = On
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = On
xdebug.remote_connect_back=1
xdebug.idekey=sublime.xdebug
```

Problem is any breakpoints set through right clicking on a line on Sublime won't work. However, setting a breakpoint as so `xdebug_stop()` works.

Am I missing something? Followed every resource I could find online to fix this issue but I can't seem to get the breakpoints working.

Seen other people ask the same question on SO but the answers provided don't seem to be working for me.
I have tried creating a Sublime project as outlined in this [tutorial](https://www.sitepoint.com/debugging-xdebug-sublime-text-3/) as well as changing the port as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42355214/4022226) but nothing seems to work.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, not a Sublime Text user here (at all), but start with collecting Xdebug log (`xdebug.remote_log`) and do that for the unsuccessful debug session (where no `xdebug_break();` (the correct function to do programmatic breakpoints) is used).

Comment: The thing I can say so far: how do you actually tell your code that you want to debug it? I mean: press the "Debug" button instead of the usual "Run"? Using some Xdebug browser extension (tat sets the Xdebug cookie for next page request)? Adding "debug me" flag manually to the requested URL (like in that tutorial)? Your Xdebug settings do not show that you are using debugger autostart (which will try to debug every single request).. so you need to do this manually.

Comment: Hi @LazyOne. So I did set remote_log to true, haven't seen any logs anywhere. I have the xdebug tabs showing up once I run Xdebug: Start session. Can't see any logs. Not unless I am looking for these logs in the wrong places.

Comment: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#remote_log -- you specify the full path for the log. ALSO: https://learnxdebug.com/

Comment: So I did get xdebug to work with VScode... why it won't work with my sublime I do not know. Thanks @LazyOne for the efforts to get me on Sublime